# verificar si usuario es mayor de edad

Tags: php, pdo

quisiera tratar de verificar antes de poder hacer un insert si el usuarios a registrarse es mayor de edad puede registrarse en el sistema, pero si es menor de edad el sistema no lo deje registrarse, ya que es requerido que sea mayor de edad para poder registrarse.

**proceso de insersión**

```
<!-- proceso para registrar-->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['guardar'])){


if($_POST['pass']!=$_POST['pass2']) { 

           $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Las Contraseñas deben coincidir !";
              header("refresh:5;registrarse.php");


  }else { 


  $sql = "SELECT cedula FROM usuarios WHERE cedula = :cedula LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
  $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
  $check->bindParam(':cedula', $_POST['cedula']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
  $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
  $contador = $check -> rowCount();//Esta función devuelve el número de resultados que ha devuelto la SELECT
  if ($contador > 0) {
  $check->closeCursor();

          $errMSG = "¡ Ups Aviso: Este usuario ya se encuentra registrado !";
              header("refresh:5;registrarse.php");
  }


  //avisame si el nombre de usuario existe
  $sql = "SELECT id_usuarios FROM usuarios WHERE user = :user LIMIT 1"; 
  //Creamos la select
  $user_check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
  $user_check->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
  $user_check->execute();
  if($user_check->rowCount() > 0){
  $user_check->closeCursor();


  $errMSG = "¡ Aviso: El nombre de usuario ya se encuetra registrado !";
  header("refresh:5;registrarse.php");


  }


  $sql= "SELECT edad FROM usuarios WHERE user = :user LIMIT 1"; //Creamos la select
  $check = $DB_con->prepare($sql); //Preparamos la SELECT, de ésta manera evitamos SQL Injection
  $check->bindParam(':edad', $_POST['edad']);//Substituimos las variables de la SELECT
  $check->execute();//Ejecutamos la consulta
  $edad = $check->fetchColumn();
  $edad=$_POST['edad'];

  if ($edad > 18){
  $check->closeCursor();


     $errMSG = "¡ Aviso: no se permiten registros a menores de edad !";
       header("refresh:5;registrarse.php");

  }

  else
  {

  $sql=$DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (user,pass,idnivel,cedula,nombres,apellidos,fecha_nac,edad,cod,telefono,direccion,id_seguros,id_servicios,observaciones) 
  VALUES (:user,:pass,:idnivel,:cedula,:nombres,:apellidos,:fecha_nac,:edad,:cod,:telefono,:direccion,:id_seguros,:id_servicios,:observaciones)");
  $sql->bindParam(':user', $_POST['user']);
  $sql->bindParam(':pass', $_POST['pass']);
  $sql->bindParam(':idnivel', $_POST['idnivel']);
  $sql->bindParam(':cedula', $_POST['cedula']);
  $sql->bindParam(':nombres', $_POST['nombres']);
  $sql->bindParam(':apellidos', $_POST['apellidos']);
  $sql->bindParam(':fecha_nac', $_POST['fecha_nac']);
  $sql->bindParam(':edad', $_POST['edad']);
  $sql->bindParam(':cod', $_POST['cod']);
  $sql->bindParam(':telefono', $_POST['telefono']);
  $sql->bindParam(':direccion', $_POST['direccion']);
  $sql->bindParam(':id_seguros', $_POST['id_seguros']);
  $sql->bindParam(':id_servicios', $_POST['id_servicios']);
  $sql->bindParam(':observaciones', $_POST['observaciones']);
  $sql->execute();

      $successMSG ="¡ Bien Hecho: Usuario registrado correctamente !";
            header("refresh:5;login.php");
         }
      }
    }
  ?>
  <!-- fin proceso para registrar-->
```

**funcion para calcular la edad**

```
  <script>
  function calcAge(dateString) {
    var birthday = +new Date(dateString);
    return ~~((Date.now() - birthday) / (31557600000));
}

function add_months(datestr, months) {
    var new_d = new Date(datestr);
    new_d.setMonth(new_d.getMonth() + months);
    return new_d;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('select').material_select();
$(".button-collapse").sideNav();
$('.modal').modal();
$('.datepicker').pickadate({
        selectMonths: true, // Creates a dropdown to control month
        selectYears: 10, // Creates a dropdown of 15 years to control year
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd', // formto de fecha  
        onClose: function() {
            $('#edad').val(calcAge($('#fecha_nac').val()));
        }
    });

 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Si es un registro nuevo y el usuario no tiene derecho a existir en la bd si no es mayor de edad, yo haría la verificación a nivel de PHP. Sería muy fácil de controlar mediante una función que calculase la edad partiendo de la fecha de nacimiento introducida en un formulario.

Comment: Puedes verificarlo antes con php y evitar ejecutar un query a la bd, el codigo que muestras no es muy relevante para el tipo de problema que quieres resolver

Comment: ok @ A. Cedano así lo hago calculo la edad con una función y tienes mucha razón ya que el registro es para usuarios nuevos por lo tanto todavía no existe ese registro déjame editar el código para mostrar como hago el calculo de la edad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo te dejo esta función para que calcules la edad sin problemas.

Puedes modificarla para que retorne `true` o `false` y en base a eso ejecutas o no la consulta de inserción.

Si lo pones a retornar `true` o `false` con hacer esto bastaría:

```
if getAge($fecha)
{
   //Es mayor, insertar

}else{

   //No eres mayor, no te puedes registrar

}
```

---

#### Código: [`ver demo`](http://rextester.com/CBYT54877)

```
<?php 


    /*
     *Calcular si es menor de 18 años
     *param: $fecha Fecha de nacimiento en el formato Y-m-d
    */

    / * Dos llamadas al método para probar * /
    getAge("1972-08-22");
    getAge("2015-07-22");


    function getAge ($fecha)
    {

        $mayor=18;

        //Creamos objeto fecha desde los valores recibidos
        $nacio = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $fecha);

        //Calculamos usando diff y la fecha actual
        $calculo = $nacio->diff(new DateTime());

        //Obtenemos la edad
        $edad=  $calculo->y;    

        if ($edad < $mayor) 
        {
            echo "Usted es menor de edad. Su edad es: $edad\n";
            //return false;  
         }else{
            echo "Usted es mayor de edad. Su edad es: $edad\n";
            //return true;  
        }
    }
?>
```

#### `Resultado:`

```
Usted es mayor de edad. Su edad es: 44
Usted es menor de edad. Su edad es: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

no seria al reves

```
if ($edad < 18)
{
   $check->closeCursor();
}
```

Para que los que sean menor de edad les aparezca el mensaje

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'